# How to set a signed 24-bit integer in a DataView?

Tags: javascript, byte, dataview, low-level, arraybuffer

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/nphyx/5c19ef4cdb9774d87e0d), but it's for unsigned 24-bit integers:

```
DataView.prototype.setUint24 = function(pos, val) {
    this.setUint16(pos, val >> 8);
    this.setUint8(pos+2, val & ~4294967040); // this "magic number" masks off the first 16 bits
}
```

Simply changing `setUint16` for `setInt16` and `setUint8` for `setInt8` doesn't seem to work. My knowledge about low level binary stuff is very limited, so I would need some help. I understand most of this function:

- `val >> 8` keeps only the first 16 bits to store as a 16-bit
- `pos + 2` is because a 16-bit integer takes 2 bytes in terms of space
- As for `val & ~4294967040`, well there's a comment lol.

I'm not too sure why just changing the calls to methods that set signed value doesn't work/ I'm not too sure why the process differs when setting signed/unsigned values.

Comment: `val & ~4294967040` is silly; `val & 0xff` would be a lot more readable. Anyway, `setUint24` should work for signed integers with no changes.

Comment: @Ryan I would at least need to use `setInt16 ` and `setInt8 ` instead of their "unsigned" alternative right? I guess something else is wrong with my code then...

Comment: No, it should work with no changes.

Comment: So I want to set a signed 24-bit integer, but using the methods to set an unsigned 16 and 8 integer works? I'm confused, but I was already confused before your reply, so I guess it doesn't change anything.

Comment: JavaScript’s integer types are 32-bit signed and unsigned integers… ish. Anything you get from a bitwise operator is a 32-bit integer. The result is signed from every operator except `>>>`, which produces an unsigned result. If you treat a signed 32-bit integer as an unsigned 32-bit integer and mask it to 24 bits, the result is the same as masking the signed one to 24 bits, and this `setUint24` implementation doesn’t actually do anything specific to unsigned integers. So I’m pretty sure it should just work. Maybe not, though.

Comment: actually the mask in the second line is completely unnecessary, since `this.setUint8(pos+2, val)` does already mask the proper bytes. Like the first line `setUint16()` "ignores" the first 2 bytes of the passed int32, and only uses the last 2 bytes

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but it's an int24 that is passed, not an int32. Wouldn't it get the first byte instead of the last byte without the mask?

Comment: @maximedupre the `>>` in `val >> 8` always creates an int32; JS only knows int32 and 64bit floats. `So I want to set a signed 24-bit integer, but using the methods to set an unsigned 16 and 8 integer works?` signed and unsigned ints use the same bits, only the interpretation is different. To keep it simple, let's talk about int8 vs uint8: the values `-128 .. -1` have the same bits as the values `128 .. 255`. The real difference will be in the `getUint24` vs `getInt24()` functions where you have to tell apart wether the leading bit is a sign or not, and interpret the remaining bits accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Ryan and @Thomas, this method works. I thought it wasn't working, because the wav file I was creating was pure white noise. It turns out that while this method works, it might be setting the bytes in the wrong order (which is problematic for wav files, but not for other processings). See [Is there anything special I have to do to create a 24-bit WAV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216723/is-there-anything-special-i-have-to-do-to-create-a-24-bit-wav-file) for more information.