# Is there anything special I have to do to create a 24-bit WAV file?

Tags: javascript, wav, audio-processing, audioformat

I can successfully create a 16-bit wav file, but when creating a 24-bit file, all I hear is white noise. I'm setting 24-bit signed integer data chunks. Do I have to set some special audio format at byte 20 in the wav file header? I'm currently using format 1.

**Edit #1**

The `wBitsPerSample` field is set to 24. The `wAvgBytesPerSec` (byte rate) field is set to

```
// 44100 * (2 * 3)
sampleRate * blockAlign
```

and `wBlockAlign` is set to

```
// 2 * 3
numChannels * bytesPerSampe
```

> Assuming you already did, the data itself needs to be 24-bit butt-to-butt (requires bit-shifting and masking unless the data already is from a 24-bit byte source). Or put differently: each sample will take 3 bytes. And as with 16-bit the byte-order matters.

I don't know if I got this part right, though.

My data comes in the form of Float32 that goes from -1 to 1 (`AudioBuffer.getChannelData()`). I then convert it to Int24:

```
function floatTo24BitPCM(output, offset, input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset += 3) {
    var s = Math.floor(input[i] * 8388608 + 0.5)
    output.setInt24(offset, s, true)
  }
}
```

and

```
DataView.prototype.setInt24 = function(pos, val, littleEndian) {
    this.setInt16(pos, val >> 8, littleEndian);
    this.setInt8(pos+2, val & ~4294967040, littleEndian); // this "magic number" masks off the first 16 bits
}
```

Does this process respect the specification (it seems like I'm doit bit shifting and masking in `setInt24`)?

**Edit #2**

Modifying

```
DataView.prototype.setInt24 = function(pos, val, littleEndian) {
    this.setInt16(pos, val >> 8, littleEndian);
    this.setInt8(pos+2, val & ~4294967040, littleEndian); // this "magic number" masks off the first 16 bits
}
```

to

```
DataView.prototype.setUint24 = function(pos, val, littleEndian) {
    this.setUint8(pos, val & ~4294967040, littleEndian); // this "magic number" masks off the first 16 bits
    this.setUint16(pos + 1, val >> 8, littleEndian);
}
```

did the trick. I assume that the byte-order was incorrect? I'm confused as to why taking the last byte and putting it before the first two bytes is the correct order.

I also suggest that this question is re-opened as it is narrow enough to not be considered as "broad" anymore.

Comment: Can you post some code to help us figure out where you're going wrong?

Comment: Kindly see my edit for the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the limited context in the post -

The field `wBitsPerSample` (inside `fmt->fmt-ck` format specific chunk, using 1 (PCM) for `wFormatTag` is fine) must reflect number of bits per sample, ie. 24 in this case.

Assuming you already did, the data itself needs to be 24-bit butt-to-butt (requires bit-shifting and masking unless the data already is from a 24-bit byte source). Or put differently: each sample will take 3 bytes. And as with 16-bit the byte-order matters.

`wAvgBytesPerSec` and `wBlockAlign` are calculated as before just with the new bit size.

Comment: Please look at my edit for more information related to your answer.

Comment: I think you pointed me in the good direction with `And as with 16-bit the byte-order matters.`. Please review my edits if you have time to add clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @maximedupre yeah, it's a byte-order problem. In the old variant the bytes are more "shuffled" while they need to be in order. little-endian reverses the order (the 16-bit write), then the MSB (here: most significant byte) or LSB is added at the wrong end. In the new variant the order is as should be.